# autocomplete done right in mobile webview

Tags: javascript, user-interface, mobile, autocomplete, user-controls

**TL;DR**

i'm looking for something like this:

[image: searchfield in ios]

implemented as some sort of UI widget in javascript.

**WHAT?**

The [autocomplete design pattern](http://ui-patterns.com/patterns/Autocomplete) is very popular in websites, giving users a comfortable and quick way to select from a big set of options.

There are numerous implementations of this pattern in javascript, such as [jquery ui autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/), but i feel that all of them fail to deliver a great UX on mobile devices.

Looking at the aforementioned jquery ui autocomplete makes this quite clear (just open the link above on your phone):

[image: jquery ui autocomplete]

Selecting from the options in the 'dropdown' is a pain, as e.g. scrolling the dropdown itself isn't possible, the whole page has to be scrolled, moving the input field out of the viewport.

Native search dialogs (like the iOS search shown above) do a much better job here, reserving all available space for the option list, with an input field at fixed position at the top.

I've found different pattern names for this behavior such as *type-ahead*, *auto-suggest* or *auto-search*, but i couldn't find a reasonable implementation in javascript. Before rolling my own: maybe someone knows something better?